# Writing cache with php-fpm and nginx on CentOS 7

Tags: php, nginx, centos7

I have tried all the possible combinations to get the Symfony's folders `cache` and `logs` writable. With no success.

The simple `chmod -R 777 cache logs` seems to set the proper chmods but still it does not write files via the browser and thrown error is "Unable to create the cache directory" or "Unable to write to cache directory".

However if run `php app/console cache:clear --env=dev` it does do the job and no error are thrown in the command line.

PHP-FPM in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf has `user` and `group` set to `apache` (tried nobdy, nginx as well). `listen` is set to 127.0.0.1:9000 if that gives any input on what is happening.

How can I make this work?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you found a resolution?

Comment: i think the problem was with SELINUX in Centos, try to disable it by typing "setenforce 0" in the console

Comment: Yeah I found that, too.  Turned it off and it worked like a charm.  Two days of my life i'll never get back!